# Can i get step by step calculation of results obtained in mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

In mathematica we generally obtain direct result instead of step by step analytical calculation. Can we somehow obtain these steps?.

Comment: Does `Trace` / `TracePrint` do what you want?

Answer (score 3):

In general, no; however, [WolfamAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) -- or calling WolframAlpha with Mathematica -- can sometimes provide step-by-step solutions.

```
WolframAlpha["Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]", {{"Result", 4}, "Content"}, 
 PodStates -> {"Result__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]